# Cannot find module whenever I add another component to React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working through a Udemy Tutorial on React, and something here does not make sense. Whenever I try to add a new component to a .js file, I get an error stating that the component file cannot be found. Here is what I mean:
Originally, I had these 2 files:

my main.js :

```js
console.log('Hello World!');
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Channel from './Channel';
 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Channel, Object.assign({}, this.props, {name:'Ryan'})),
    document.getElementById('My-Channel')
  );
});
```

and my Channel

```js
import React from 'react';


class Channel extends React.Component {
 onClick(){
  console.log('I was clicked');
 }
 render(){
  return(
   <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>{this.props.name}</li>
   )
 }
}

export default Channel;
```

This code actually works, and displays the proper 1 item list.

However, when I try to add another component to my Channel.js file, it breaks. No matter what I put in, it seems that adding another component does not work. 
Ex :

```js
import React from 'react';


class Channel extends React.Component {
 onClick(){
  console.log('I was clicked');
 }
 render(){
  return(
   <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>{this.props.name}</li>
   )
 }
}
class ChannelList extends React.Component{
 render(){
  return (
   <ul>
    <Channel name='Hardware Support'>
   </ul>
  )
 }
}
export default Channel;
```

Do I have to create a new file every time I want to create a component? I can't imagine that being the case, so what would you suggest I do?
[Here is the Exact Error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRbtt.png)

[Even if I add a simple dictionary to the end of the file, I get the same error. Its as if the only thing in this Channel.js file can be the channel component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68YFF.png)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: what is using ChannelList -- perhaps you need to export that also.

Comment: I am using ChannelList as an <ul> of Channel <li> items. Please see my edit where I added an image of the error @jamesemanon

Comment: you're putting `Channel` inside `ChannelList`... but are you still passing `Channel` to `ReactDOM.render`? That would surely break it.

Comment: @azium , yes, I was still passing Channel to ReactDOM.render. However, when I take that out, and only include the ChannelList, It still gives the same error

Comment: I'm guessing you have a syntax error in your `Channel` file.. you have one in your example.. you forgot to put the closing forward slash in `<Channel name='Hardware Support'>`  you need `/>` at the end of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not being able to find a module is almost always a sign of a syntax error (assuming the files are in the right location). In your case, it's never hitting `export` because the following is a syntax error:

```
class ChannelList extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <ul>
                <Channel name='Hardware Support'>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

You're missing the closing tag!

Change `<Channel name='Hardware Support'>` to `<Channel name='Hardware Support' />`

Also it looks as though you should be doing:

```
export default ChannelList
```

and in your main file:

```
import ChannelList from './Channel'

ReactDOM.render(
  <ChannelList />,
  document.getElementById('My-Channel')
),
```

Comment: This is everything. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @jamesemanon for part of the solution, and @azium for the other.

So, of the problems that I had:

1. make sure to close your tags
2. for some reason, I had to use export default instead of just
   export
3. I had to import ChannelList into my main.js file : import
   ChannelList from './Channel';

Thank you both for your help, I hope some others can benefit from this in the future as well